# What striking oriented arts will complement wrestling/grappling MMA practice

Tags: mixed-martial-arts, striking

I do mixed martial arts (Jujitsu, Aikido, Judo, not too much Boxing and Iaido).
We do strike, but we don't get taught ways to strike well. I want to do another martial art that focuses on striking rather than grappling (what we spar pretty much all the time now). This is to maybe compete in the future but mainly for self improvement

What martial art(s) will complement what I do already?

Due to a lot off people telling me to change my question (rightly so) I am going to add some info on me:

Height-5ft 11 
weight-11st
I am bigger in size than average
I have started doing calisthenics recently

Sorry for this late update, I didn't see the "show more comments button"

Please note, there is no Mauy Tai anywhere near me.

Comment: What is best for you is nebulous and impossible to answer -- hence the vote to close. Could you refine your question to point out what your goals are and what you are looking for: competition, self defence, general why not?…

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Please read the help doco [*What topics can I ask about here?*](http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Your question is closed for now, but if you re-word it we can look to reopen it.

Comment: You've edited the question but it is still a "what's best?" question. I'd suggest you change it to ask what striking oriented arts will complement your wrestling/grappling MMA practice. You should also include more detail - for example you mention there is no Muay Thai nearby, but what about other arts like karate/hapkido/kung fu/etc.

Comment: As @slugster says, you edited the question, but haven't included more detail on your goals. Are you intending to compete? Are you training for self-defence, or personal improvement? What do you get out of your current syllabus and why do you want to extend that?

Comment: You do not get to re-open the question yourself. The community will vote to re-open it when it deems the question is good. Currently, as has been said, you have not included any goals so it makes the question impossible to answer.

Comment: I'm agreed that this is too broad/opinion-based as it stands now.

Comment: @Owen When you edit your closed question it enters a queue that more experienced users can see, at this point they can make a decision whether the edits have been sufficient to reopen it. Currently I see one reopen vote, be patient and allow more of the community to see it, someone may edit it even further for you.

Comment: The problem with this question is that it provides no real guidance for what you are looking for other than striking but not Muay Thai, which will result in each answerer suggesting whatever striking style they practice and everyone getting in a shouting match. (As you can see, you already have a Muay Thai answer anyway.) To get better answers, you can describe the striking options available, your body type (tall, short, stocky, lean, etc.), why your boxing training has been inadequate, and anything else you can think of that can be used to evaluate answers.

Answer (score 1):

It is a personal opinion but I feel as though these arts, Muay Thai in particular incorporates all elements of striking. At the end of the day I don't think it matters what the style is as long as you have a good coach who know what they are talking about.

If there's no Muay Thai then I'd say boxing or kickboxing is your next best option. You may be able to try and self learn a few moves and then incorporate them into sparing.

Comment: Yep. It's the same suggestion that I also can give. Boxing and Kick Boxing would be great. Also putting an effort to learn some taekwondo would be recommended as well.

Comment: It's a personal opinion but I feel as though these arts, Muay Thai in particular incorporates all elements of striking. At the end of the day I don't think it matters what the style is as long as you have a good coach who know what they are talking about